# Allowing comma separated values in textbox using regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation, textbox

In my asp.net application I have one textbox where I want to allow comma separated values, e.g.

```
name1,name1,name3
```

I have one regular expression for checking values i.e. single value (`name1` or `name2` or `name3`) must satisfy regular expression `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*`.

Now I want to check this both validations using single regular expression

1. single value must satisfy `[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*` regular expression
2. Textbox must have comma separated values.

I am not able to create proper regEx for this.

Comment: In a `textbox` you can insert comma separated values without using a regular expression. Usually, a regular expression is used for input validation. Do you want to allo only comma separated values to be inserted in your input control?

Comment: This is just lazy. You just need to add `,?` before your current regex and repeat all your regex 0 to n time

Comment: Why make life hard for yourself? Just split on `,`, trim spaces, and then just check against your current regex? Unless you have a weird business requirement to only use regex...

Comment: @Christos I just want to allow comma separated values .

Comment: @Ploutox Thanx for giving tag of Lazy to me but I am very bad at regular expressions, that is why I asked here.

Comment: @Enigmativity I cant do this way.

Comment: @vaibhavshah - Why not?

Comment: @Enigmativity Maybe he's using a [regular expression validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx). Maybe the existing solution is regex and he doesn't want to rearchitect it. Maybe he just likes regular expressions. I wish people wouldn't answer regular expression questions with "lol y u use regex".

Comment: @Rawling - Thanks for the response. I didn't say "LOL" or anything like it. I've got no problem with regex, other than the more you try to recognize with it the harder it is to maintain.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, I let the lolspeak get the better of me :)

Comment: @Enigmativity I will do it your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*(?:,[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                         # Start of string
[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*   # Match a single value
(?:                       # Start of non-capturing group
 ,                        # Match a comma
 [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*  # Match a single value
)*                        # Repeat non-capturing group as often as necessary
$                         # End of string
```

If you're using that regex client-side (i.e. according to ECMAScript rules), you can simplify it to

```
(?i)^[a-z]+[\w-]*(?:,[a-z]+[\w-]*)*$
```